# GCM Chrome: Empty Data Response

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-messaging, service-worker, chrome-gcm

i am currently integrating gcm in my web application, the subscription and the registration_id saving working, i get on the client also the response, when i trigger a message from Postman. So now i need to transfer the title and the message.
i am triggering the gcm api with this parameter: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PC0fs.png and thats the received from the client: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdYHl.png

The Field "data" is everytime empty,

Answer (score 4):

Despite using GCM as its push service, Chrome doesn't support payloads using the GCM method.

It supports payloads encrypted using the [Web Push encryption standard](https://webpush-wg.github.io/webpush-encryption/). See also the [blog post on the developers.google.com website](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/03/web-push-encryption).

You can either implement it yourself, or use a library such as [web-push](https://github.com/marco-c/web-push) for Node.js or [pywebpush](https://github.com/jrconlin/pywebpush) for Python or [web-push](https://github.com/Minishlink/web-push) for PHP.