# Service workers with FCM get data in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm try to implement Push Notifications in Chrome with ServiceWorkers and GCM.

The notifications working fine, but the push function the event is null (`self.addEventListener('push', function(event)`).

The next is my code and working fine, received the notifications, but don't receive the data.

To register:

```
<script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

            /*navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration().then(function(r) { 
             r.unregister();
             });*/

           // document.querySelector("#enablepush").addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                //if(Notification.permission !== 'granted') {
                Notification.requestPermission().then(function (permission) {
                    if (permission === 'granted' && 'serviceWorker' in navigator) {
                        navigator.serviceWorker.register('myworker.js').then(initialiseState);
                    } else {
                        console.log('service worker not present');
                    }
                });
                //} 
          //  });
            //get subscription token if already subscribed
            if (Notification.permission === 'granted') {
                navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function (registration) {
                    registration.pushManager.getSubscription().then(function (subscription) {
                        getToken(subscription);
                    });
                });
            }
        });



        function SalirPush()
        {
            console.log("Si registro ha sido cancelado");
            navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration().then(function (r) {
                r.unregister();
            });

            navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function (reg) {
                reg.pushManager.getSubscription().then(function (subscription) {
                    subscription.unsubscribe().then(function (successful) {
                        // You've successfully unsubscribed
                    }).catch(function (e) {
                        // Unsubscription failed
                    })
                })
            });
        }


        function initialiseState() {

            //check if notification is supported or not
            if (!('showNotification' in ServiceWorkerRegistration.prototype)) {
                console.warn('Notificaiton are not supported');
                return;
            }
            //check if user has blocked push notification
            if (Notification.permission === 'denied') {
                console.warn('User has blocked the notification');
            }
            //check if push messaging is supported or not
            if (!('PushManager' in window)) {
                console.warn('Push messaging is not supported');
                return;
            }

            //subscribe to GCM
            navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function (serviceWorkerRegistration) {
                //call subscribe method on serviceWorkerRegistration object
                serviceWorkerRegistration.pushManager.subscribe({userVisibleOnly: true})
                        .then(function (subscription) {
                            getToken(subscription);
                            var met = JSON.stringify(subscription);
                            console.log("Mensaje", met);
                        }).catch(function (err) {
                    console.error('Error occured while subscribe(): ', err);
                });
            });
        }

        function getToken(subscription) {
            console.log(subscription);
            var token = subscription.endpoint.substring(40, subscription.endpoint.length);
            //document.querySelector("#token").innerHTML = token;
            try
            {
                $("#apikey").val(token);
            }catch (e)
            {

            }
        }
    </script>
```

Next my workers.js is;

```
self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {    
 var url = "/push/json-data.php?param=(This is the event data info)";
  event.waitUntil(  
    fetch(url).then(function(response) {  
      if (response.status !== 200) {  
        // Either show a message to the user explaining the error  
        // or enter a generic message and handle the
        // onnotificationclick event to direct the user to a web page  
        console.log('Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: ' + response.status);  
        throw new Error();  
      }

      // Examine the text in the response  
      return response.json().then(function(data) {  
        if (data.error || !data.notification) {  
          console.log('The API returned an error.', data.error);  
          throw new Error();  
        }  
        var title = data.notification.title;  
        var message = data.notification.message;  
        var icon = data.notification.icon;  

        return self.registration.showNotification(title, {  
          body: message,  
          icon: icon,  
          data: {
            url: data.notification.url
          }  
        });  
      });  
    }).catch(function(err) {  
      console.log('Unable to retrieve data', err);

      var title = 'An error occurred';
      var message = 'We were unable to get the information for this push message';  
      var icon = 'img/design19.jpg';  
      var notificationTag = 'notification-error';  
      return self.registration.showNotification(title, {  
          body: message,  
          icon: icon,  
          tag: notificationTag  
        });  
    })  
  );  
});

// The user has clicked on the notification ...
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {  
  console.log(event.notification.data.url);
  // Android doesn't close the notification when you click on it  
  // See: http://crbug.com/463146  
  event.notification.close();

  // This looks to see if the current is already open and  
  // focuses if it is  
  event.waitUntil(
    clients.matchAll({  
      type: "window"  
    })
    .then(function(clientList) {  
      for (var i = 0; i < clientList.length; i++) {  
        var client = clientList[i];  
        if (client.url == '/' && 'focus' in client)  
          return client.focus();  
      }  
      if (clients.openWindow) {
        return clients.openWindow(event.notification.data.url);  
      }
    })
  );
});
```

Next to send the Push Notifications, I use this PHP:

```
    <?php

$estado=$_GET["estado"];
$idtoken=$_GET["id"];
$op=$_GET["op"];

if ($op != "")
{
sendFCM("My App","Hi to all", $idtoken,$estado);
}
function sendFCM($titulo,$mess,$id,$estado) {
    echo "Recibi: $mess , $id, $estado";
    $data = array('status'=> $estado,'mensaje'=>'"'.$mess.'"','titulo'=>'"'.$titulo.'"');
$url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
$fields = array (
        'to' => $id,
        'notification' => array (
                "body" => $mess,
                "title" => $titulo,
                "icon" => "myicon",
            "color"=> "#0000ff",
            "sound" => "default"

        ),
    'data' => $data,
    'payload' => $data
);

$fields = json_encode ( $fields );
$headers = array (
        'Authorization: key=' . "MyGoogleKey",
        'Content-Type: application/json'
);

$ch = curl_init ();
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields );

$result = curl_exec ( $ch );
curl_close ( $ch );
echo ($result);
}

?>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have the same issue but I am confusing about /push/json-data.php page.

Comment: My json-data.php is to can consult in my database all info arround of the notifications. But im need recived in the "event" one data (the id or any other info to make the consult in my database)

Comment: Probably http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38992034/web-push-notification-payload-data-is-getting-null, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37088397/gcm-chrome-empty-data-response

Answer (score 0):

use `event.data.json().data` in your push event:

```
self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
    event.waitUntil(
        self.registration.pushManager.getSubscription().then(function(subscription) {
            console.info(event.data.json().data);
        });
    );  
});
```